# Use datatables.net with javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, multidimensional-array, datatables

So I have a few javascript arrays, ex. `array1 = [1,2,3]` and `array2 = [4,5,6]` and I want these arrays to represent the column data, not row data like it wants.
How would I make the table to look like:

[image: This]

I've been pulling my hair out all day, and I can't seem to find a solution......is this even supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply output the data how you need it.

```
var rows = '';

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { //assumes equal size arrays
  rows += '<tr><td>'+array[i]+'</td><td>'+array2[i]+'</td></tr>';
  //or however you do this
}
```

Comment: He is using the [datatables](https://datatables.net/) jquery plugin which accepts data as a javascript array. He just has to format his array differently.

Comment: yeah, that uses html right?, but I was looking to use datatables.net or bootstrap tables for its added functionality......so I guess I just have to figure out how to reformat the array?>

Comment: @Andrew In the most basic example it operates on an existing table, that's why i took this approach https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: Really, it doesn't matter though. You could use the same logic to restructure the data instead.

Comment: @aw04, that's a very clever approach.  Maybe making that basic table and then converting it to the datatables.net might do the trick.....

Answer (score 6):

Going off aw04's [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751624/2518200), here is a way to do it by creating a new array by transposing the columns and rows. Use this method if you are generating the table [based on data you have in a javascript array](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html).

```
var rows = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { 
    rows.push([array1[i],array2[i]]);
}
```

Just make sure that array1 has the same number of elements as array2.

Comment: yep this is what i'd do actually if it will just create the table for you, my answer is probably an extra step

Comment: Yeah that's an easy way too, push them together. Thanks!